# Resize shapes on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, webgl

Is possible resize geometric shapes on the fly using JavaScript?

Example: I have a rectangle and two fields (length and height).

When user define some measure, resize it.

I thought OpenGL, WebGL, SVG, VRML .. I was thinking something that would works well on browsers without use plugins.

Comment: There's no single technology you can use that works across browsers new and old. (Well, unless you want to lay out "pixel divs" yourself ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

> http://raphaeljs.com/

Use it wisely :)

***Hint:** You can use `path` for random shapes.*

Here's a simple example for your amusement: http://jsfiddle.net/HeJDJ/

Comment: You should be aware that rescaling paths can be rather expensive if you do enough of it since Raphaël 1.x rewrites the entire path instead of setting a scale 'transform' attribute.

Comment: Maybe the solution is to check how much has changed in percentage in all measures, then apply the changes. For example: If all measures have increased by 20%, nothing happens. Any advice is very welcome.

Comment: @coffe The [`scale`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#scale) method may help you.

Comment: Scale only changes the 'x'and 'y' image. To change the measures I think it's necessary to make a function that will check how much has changed in some measure against other measures. With this, change the ALL path.
Need to do some study for each shape.  :/

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the [Raphael.JS](http://raphaeljs.com/) library? SVG is pretty much cross-platform, and does not need any plugin. It should work for your application.